# Having problems with C Command-line calculator with multiple numbers and operators

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm newbie to programming, and the goal is to make calculator that can handle multiple numbers and operators (as many as the user wants, up to 100 in total).

There are three requirements.

1. A series of a symbol for the calculation and a positive integer
2. Calculation symbol is either '+' or '-'
3. The maximum number of (symbol, number) pairs is 100

The output should be like this

```
$ program.exe 10 - 20 + 35 - 27
-2
```

But, if I launch this program via cmd, nothing happens.

The code I tried is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    int a, b, rst;
    int i;
    char opr;

    if (argc > 100)
    {
        printf("Too many arguments!");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (argc < 1)
    {
        printf("There are no arguments!");
        return 0;
    }

    a = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (i = 1; argv[i]; i++)
    {
        b = argv[2*i + 1];
        opr = argv[2*i - 1];
        switch (opr)
        {
        case '+':rst = a + b;
            break;
        case '-':rst = a - b;
            break;
        }

        rst = a;
    }
    printf("%d", rst);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Need to add new line `\n` to your `printf()` formats.

Comment: Towards the second half of the loop, `argv[2*i + 1]` would clearly access an index out of bounds.

Comment: Don't forget that if the program is invoked `program.exe` (no extra arguments), then `argc == 1`.  You probably need to revise the `else if (argc < 1)` test to use `<=`.

Comment: Calculate `2*i + 1` for a few values of `i`. Calculate `2*i - 1` for a few values of `i`. Is this what you want to see?